# Google Maps/Directions using mouse drag

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm looking for some JavaScript utility (or something like that) for displaying driving directions. I'm looking for almost the same as [Google Maps/Directions](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/directions/). Notice, when you create a route between 2 places you might use mouse drag and drop functionality to manually modify it. I'm looking for exactly the same functionality for my web site.

Could you please tell if such library or utility exist?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called the Google Maps API which has driving directions:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
and you can make them draggable:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DraggableDirections